# What is the best method or algorithm to produce a less value of Mean Square Error(MSE)?

Tags: algorithm, methods

If I have two vectors

A = {8, 6, 5, 7}

B = {1, 3, 2, 4}

What is the best method or algorithm to **subtract** each element in **A** from anthor element in **B** **(without repeating the elements)** to produce a less value of **Mean Square Error(MSE)** ?

Comment: Hint: Suppose we have two numbers a1 and a2 from A, and two numbers b1 and b2 from B, and a1 < a2 and b1 < b2.  a1 can be paired with b1 or with b2 (leaving a2 to be paired with whichever of b1 and b2 is left)...  Is one of these choices always better for the overall total score?

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I got it. Thank you